# How to make images single light box?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have more than 5 images.

When i click on image its expanding.

Problem is Here it should show only one light box.

All the images should be in one light box.

When i clik on images it should start sliding.

I mean all the images should be in one div.

Here is my code.

Here images are displaying individually instead of thet in one div all the images should be availbale.

Please check the link i want to display images and data like that

https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-rent/residential-real-estate?proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Service-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa,Paying-Guest,Hostel,Commercial-Office-Space,Office-ITPark-SEZ,Commercial-Shop,Commercial-Showroom,Commercial-Land,Industrial-Land,Warehouse/-Godown,Industrial-Building,Industrial-Shed&inputListings=I&cityName=Bangalore

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found simple solution if you have a lot of pictures, you don't have to add rel to each. Just surround images with div with class e.g. lightbox-group

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.lightbox-group').each(function(){
        $(this).find('a').lightBox();                     
     });    
});
```

```html
<div class="lightbox-group" id="first">
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
</div>

<div class="lightbox-group" id="second">
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir thank you. But i want design my pictures like this https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-rent/residential-real-estate?proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Service-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa,Paying-Guest,Hostel,Commercial-Office-Space,Office-ITPark-SEZ,Commercial-Shop,Commercial-Showroom,Commercial-Land,Industrial-Land,Warehouse/-Godown,Industrial-Building,Industrial-Shed&inputListings=I&cityName=Bangalore   ... You can see there 16 pic in one photo div. when i click on that it explores all the images with slide.